# NoSuchMethodError when taking Screenshot

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to take a Screanshot of a Stak with a list of iteams in it. It displays normaly and works, but when i try to take screenshot of the Widget I resive:
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'stateWidget' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: stateWidget)
(I use a Inhereted widget)

Her is the Widget I am trying to take a Screenshot of

```
class BlinkSkjerm extends StatelessWidget {


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final provider = InheritedDataProvider.of(context);
    final data = provider.historikken[provider.index];

return SizedBox(
    height: 400,
    child: Stack(
      children: data.inMoveableItemsList,
    ));
  }
}
```

and her is the onPress funtion:

```
onPressed: () async {
    final controler = ScreenshotController();
    final bytes = await controler.captureFromWidget(BlinkSkjerm());
    setState(() {
      this.bytes = bytes;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please post the error from your console or terminal here, need to see the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you used InheritedDataProvider in wrong way. you did not provide data that needed in BlinkSkjerm.

you want to take screen shot from widget that not in the tree, but that widget  need data that should provide before build it which you did not provide it.

this approach work this way:

```
Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => InheritedDataProvider(
                        child: BlinkSkjerm(),
                        data:'some string',
                      )),
                );
```

this way you can use

```
final provider = InheritedDataProvider.of(context);
```

and make sure it is not null.

for your situation I recommended to do something like this:

```
onPressed: () async {
    final controler = ScreenshotController();
    final bytes = await controler.captureFromWidget(InheritedDataProvider(
                            child: BlinkSkjerm(),
                            data:'some string',
                          ));
    setState(() {
      this.bytes = bytes;
    });
  }
```

for more information see this [page](https://medium.com/@sexycode/flutter-pass-data-with-inheritedwidget-2d9bcb68ee0)

Comment: I updated my answer, hope its help you

Comment: thans that solved it:)

Comment: I'm glad that helps you to fix your problem, I appreciate if you give it up vote too.